Why am I getting a "Following unit is out of order." error (SC 990-00) on a Ricoh Aficio MP 4002 SP?
Why am I getting a "Following unit is out of order." error (SC 990-00) on a Ricoh Aficio MP 4002 SP?
I've been facing this issue for 4 months so far, I get this error randomly every 1 to 2 hours on regular basis, sometimes while printing or copying, sometimes when it's on sleeping mode.
I cleaned RAM, formatted the hard drive, changed the drum, even removed the scanner, but it's still existed.
I installed the latest version from Ricoh website, but the problem still existed. any ideas?


To ask the 'obvious' - have you called for service?

unfortunately we don't have ricoh support in Egypt, and the maintenance guys can't solve the problem.

I'm not sure which Ricoh devices it applies to, but is ERR (990) or ERR (999) is displayed on the control panel found on the Ricoh website any help?

From the Ricoh manual:

Code: 990-00
Causes: An unexpected operation was encountered by the software.
Remedy:

Software crash, reboot the machine
If the HDDs have just been replaced, be sure to download the stamp data (SP 5853).
With SP5990 004(SMC Report – Logging Data), print the most recent information for SC990.
The SC990 information displays the file name, line number, and value.
Report this information to your technical supervisor.
For example: Function.c LINE: 123 VAL: 0


You've already rebooted the machine.
You've formatted the HDD.
Have you reset the HDD using SP mode 5853? There are various online suggestions for doing so.

Copytechnet.com:

Yellow C key button then press numbers 107 and hold down grey C button
Hold down the COPY key while you turn on the machine.


Spiceworks.com
Press the HOMEbutton (Just to give you a clean starting place).
Press the Reset (Yellow) key.
On the number pad enter  107.
Press and Hold the C key.



Thank you for your response, but many technical supervisors have tried to solve this problem but all failed to do so, and we don't have ricoh support here in egypt, specially in my city, that's why i'm looking for help here.
i did what you have said and here's the result " No = - / Name = SC-990-00 / Value = 93 " so is there anything i can do myself?

Only SP 5853, as stated in answer.

I did the SP 5853 thing yesterday and stayed for 2 hours without any errors then work time was over, I'll check it out today, i'll keep you posted, thank you so much.

DrMoishe Pippik, I'm really thankful for your help, i did the SP 5853 thing, and already went for like 8 hours without any error alert and no restart, but after 8 hours, it came back again while the printer was in sleeping mode. any more ideas please?

@AdelRashed, Sorry, that was all I found in the manual.
